# 403 forbidden error raised while Initializing BrowserFetcher in PuppeteerSharp

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I am trying to use the PuppeteerSharp headless browser in my project and it doesn't even initialize.

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => 
{
    await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
    var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
    {
        Headless = false
    });
    var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
    await page.SetUserAgentAsync("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36");
    await page.GoToAsync("https://sample.com");
    html = await page.GetContentAsync();
});
task.Wait();
```

When it reached to the `await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);` this exeption is raised:

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Comment: Depending on the platform. The only URL that `DownloadAsync` would use will be something like https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/674921/chrome-win.zip. Maybe you are not able to access that URL?  If not, what platform are running Puppeteer on?

Comment: @hardkoded Oh, I see, googleapis.com restricts IPs from my country. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For me the issue seems to be related to using .net core 3.0 or higher. I get the same 403 error if I use BrowserFetcher or ExecutablePath. However using .net core 2.X seems to work fine in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might not be able to access to `https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/674921/chrome-win.zip`.
If you can't access to that URL, you can try to download a Chromium 77 (or greater) manually, and use the [ExecutablePath](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.LaunchOptions.html#PuppeteerSharp_LaunchOptions_ExecutablePath) property to set the Chromium app location.